# Why in C# Console.ReadLine() stores only string?

Tags: c#, console.readline

Why can't Console.ReadLine() store int/double in C# ? As opposed to "cin >>" in C++, which can store anything depending on the variable.

Comment: `Console.Readline()` just reads in a string value.  The console has no idea what type of value you're going to type in.  c++ doesnt allow this either, but it does allow you to shoot yourself in the foot when the types dont match.

Comment: In C++, what happens when you try to read the input "Hello World" as an int?

Comment: Why questions are difficult, only the BCL team could answer for sure. But Console input is used much less than when C/C++ were introduced. Just not worth the effort. Read a line and process it.

Comment: @David : about the same as `int.Parse("Hello")` in C#.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Exactly :)  The functionality is no different, C# is just a little more explicit about it.

Comment: No, that's a false comparison. This is a question about a feature set, not error handling.

Answer (score 7):

Different language, different library, different API, different design decisions, etc.

`cin.operator>>` is passed a reference to be used an out parameter and it's overloaded on this parameter type. `Console.ReadLine` *returns* a value and is not overloaded.

You could write your own extension method for `Console` like, say, `GetValue`, which is passed an out parameter and is overloaded on as many types as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

The console, natively, is just text input.  `Console.ReadLine()` (and the other methods) don't do the parsing for you, and instead leave it up to you to parse yourself.

This has an advantage, however, in that it makes it easier to handle the error cases cleanly (if you want to read in a double, and the user types "foo", for example).

Answer (score 0):

Because it is more safe to read a string. It prevents such errors as bad data in C++ when as a result the state of the stream becames erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Console.ReadLine() stores strings because this is how it built.
But, you can check your input and make casting to the type you would like.

for example, you can do like that:

```
string sen = Console.ReadLine();
int b;
int.TryParse(sen, out b);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

You can use the code above to take an input and then put in b the result as an int.
If the input was not a number for example then b will store 0.

If you want to do that to double then you should do double.TryParse and put it on a double variable.